# MultiJson::DecodeError while send ajax request in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
  url:'/monitoring',
  type:'POST',
  data: {checked:{a:1}},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(){
  }
});
```

The following exception has thrown when I send this request:

**MultiJson::DecodeError**

unexpected token at **'checked%5Ba%5D=1'**

What is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution. It's worked now (see Content-Type):

```
$.ajax({
  headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  url:'/monitoring',
  type:'POST',
  data: {checked:{a:1}},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(){
  }
});
```